# Run a excel function which references excel cell as a argument but this function should run only when row or column changes not value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hii I am a fresher to excel and apologise for possibly uneducated question. I need a function that references a excel cell and run when its argument cell reference row or column changes not value

Scenario of expected behaviour:

lets say cell D5 value is 123 and I have a function =test(D5)
Now if I add a column after B column the excel automatically updates the cell reference to E5
So I need that this cell reference should get updated to =test(D5) but the function should not run

Also I cannot change the excel calculation type to manual

So any guidance or solution will be very appreciated

Comment: Not sure exactly what your question is, but does `=TEST(INDEX(D:D,5))` do what you want?

Comment: No , what I need is when I add a new coumn after B column the function on cell E5(=test(D5)) which is using D5 cell address should update  to E5 but the function  should not run. The behaviour I am asking is shown by excel when sheet is in manual mode but I cannot set manual mode

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Thought so but thank you for your time